# Print only variables that are True Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have a list of variables. Some are equal to True, some are not. I would like to know the easiest way to print only ones that are 'True'. It doesn't matter what order they are printed, but they need to be separated by a blank line in the output.

For example:

```
Var1 = "Cat"
Var2 = "Dog"
Var3 = "Sheep"
Var4 = ""
Var5 = ""
Var6 = "Horse"
```

And I need to somehow get the system to print:

```
Cat

Dog

Sheep

Horse
```

I was thinking something like:

```
print True in [Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6]
```

But obviously that doesn't work as it doesn't seem to be correct usage (I was just guessing). Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: `Var1`, `Var2`, etc... is a common anti-pattern. Use a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although, as noted in a comment to your question, `VarX, VarY, ...` is a common anti pattern and you should rather use a list, you could use:

```
print('\n'.join(filter(bool, [Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6])))
```

Comment: `filter` is quite nice here. But there is a syntax error in this code.

Comment: With Python 3 indeed where `print` is a function

Comment: Thanks for this! This got me the closest to where I needed to be. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 4):

To save building a string in memory use `filter` and the `sep=` argument for `print`:

```
items = (var1, var2, var3) # etc...
print (*filter(None, items), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, this info got me to where I needed to be along with the previous answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
print([var for var in [Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6] if var])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print ('\n'.join([var for var in [Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5, Var6] if var]))
```

Comment: Updated...I guess it will now. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: @BlaXpirit You using Python 2 or 3?